# 404 Not Found with All Cloaking plugins

Tags: redirect

I don't know why I always see that problem "404 Not Found " When I opened the Cloaking links  I used Pretty link plugin and another one
I just Setup my blog, hope someone help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file was missing Now It works